# C++ add char to char[1024]

Tags: c++, char

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char command[1024];
    char newchar;
    cout << "Command Line Interface Test with Intellisense" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    newchar = _getch();
    command = command + newchar;
}
```

Why does this not work?

Why command = command + newchar is wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I guess you want command[0] = newchar;

Comment: if command = `abc` and newchar = `d`, then the result should be `abcd`.

Comment: No it wasn't. I want to append `newchar` to `command`.

Comment: @ToolBox `command` is a fixed size array, you can't append anything to it.

Comment: SO... what can I do? Should I use `string` instead?

Comment: @ToolBox: `std::string` is certainly a more convenient way to manage strings than mucking around with low-level arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `std::string` and `append` the char to it.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append

Or with C++11, you can use the += operator with std::string

(You will have to #include string header)

Comment: Visual C++ 2013, sir.

Comment: You can do this in Visual C++ after including the string header

Answer (score 0):

In `command + newchar`, command becomes a (const) pointer and newchar is an integer value, so you are making a pointer to a "bigger" address, but when assigning the result to `command`, you are trying to change the (const) pointer to an array, which luckily is not allowed.

```
char* pNew = command + newchar;
```

This would have worked, but not doing as expected.  As others already answered: use std::string.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because C++ is statically typed. A `char[1024]` object will stay the same type for its entire life, and it can't change to a `char[1025]`. The same applies to a `std::string`, but the *size* of a string is not part of its type and can therefore change:

```
std::string command = "abc";
comamnd += "d";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are You trying to do something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(){

    char command[BUFFER_SIZE];

    cout << "Command Line Interface Test with Intellisense" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; ++i)
        char newchar = _getch();
        if(newchar == '\n') break;

        // do some magic with newchar if you wish

        command[i] = newchar;
    }

}
```